# Getting white screen of death on deployed Laravel app

Tags: php, fortrabbit

Earlier today my Laravel app on Fortrabbit was working fine but after pushing to the app white pages started to be displayed instead of any content. I can still directly access any assets by explicitly specifying the path but if I try to access my index page or any other that work both locally and on previous versions of the application I get a white screen with no content.

I've tried removing the /vendor directory and composer.lock and updating composer to get a fresh start. I've also looked into the logs given by the Fortrabbit service in the php and apache directories and neither are reporting errors. I've also looked into the logs for Laravel and this also didn't provide any error messages that could help me debug the issue.

Was wondering if anyone had experience with this issue and could offer steps to attempt to resolve it, thank you!

Notes:

- I'm using Laravel v4.1.*
- The commit that began causing the issue contained no changes to PHP code (only SCSS files)
- I've run `php artisan dump-autoload` already
- I can run `php artisan tinker` and interact with the MySQL database just fine with my models

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master"
    }, 
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: I Josh Black. Have you solved your issue ? What was it ?

Comment: @edi9999 yupp I did, I was using an environment variable for the application key which was entered incorrectly on Fortrabbit. This caused the application to fail.